# Can't get sector size of VHDX changed?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, hyper-v, vhd

I have been hopelessly trying to change the sector size of a freshly created Windows 10 VHDX file, to 4096 bytes per sector.

After searching the net and trying things, this comes closest (using Windows 10):

- [Install Hyper-V](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_install)
- Select Start button and type Powershell
- Right mouse click "Run as Administrator"
- Type command: `Set-Vhd -Path 4Kn.vhdx –PhysicalSectorSizeBytes 4096`

The latter command has been tried in all possible flavors, with full path, just the filename (after CD'ing to the folder) etc.

I always get errors:

```
Set-Vhd : The operation on computer 'DESKTOP-JCMNHRV' failed: Invalid class
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Vhd -Path C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\4Kn.vhdx –PhysicalSectorSizeByte ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-VHD], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unspecified,Microsoft.Vhd.PowerShell.Cmdlets.SetVhd
```

Any idea what to do or where to start? I don't see it anymore

The .vhdx is not attached, and I tried without any formatting inside, and later with an NTFS formatted volume.

Comment: [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) might be a better place for this question.

Comment: Got it to work.  Hyper-V didn't seem properly installed.  I tried again via the powershell: `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All` and after that the command worked

Comment: I had similar issue. The problem in my case was **a)** that the vhdx was mounted (Dah.) and **b)** the path to unmounted vhdx contained NTFS junction (for some reason it matters).